# Parsing an xml using javascript

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, domparser

This is running in IE browser.

This is my xml

```
<fields>

                <from><type>string</type><value> India</value></from>

                <number><type>string</type><value>1231</value></number>

                <aDate><type>string</type><value>2022-04-12</value></aDate>          

</fields>
```

Trying to parse this xml and fetch the values

Excpected result is

India1231

2022-04-12

```
if (window.DOMParser){

  parser=new DOMParser();

  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

} else // Internet Explorer {

  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

  xmlDoc.async=false;

  xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);

  var fieldLen = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fields").length;

  var from= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from").childNodes[1].nodeValue; // line 9

  var number= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("number").childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  var aDate= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("aDate").childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}
```

This gives parsing error at  line no 9

Comment: IE7 is *ancient*.  IE8 is over a decade old. Why on earth are you trying to support it in 2022?

Comment: ya I know, but that is my requirement. Its an old system.